# How to test a hover event that changes CSS in a MUI StyledComponent with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm facing an issue with testing this event with MUI and StyledComponent. Any of you know how to test this behavior?

Here is my MUI component and my jest test:

```
const App = () => {

const GridTr = styled(Grid)(() => {
  return {
    height: '30px',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    },
  };
});

return ( < GridTr data-testid="grid-tr" > My Grid Component < /GridTr>)
}
```

Jest Test

```
it('renders gray bg when mouse hover',function () {
   
    const { getByTestId } = render(<GridTr data-testid="grid-tr" />);

    const gridTr = getByTestId('grid-tr');
    
   fireEvent.mouseEnter(gridTr);
    
    expect(gridTr).toHaveStyle('background-color: #f5f5f5');
});
```

I tried using an async userEvent also but had no success.

In both tests this is the output:

```
 expect(element).toHaveStyle()

- Expected

- background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
```

---

This is just a simple hover but if you with to see in working mode here is

```js
const {
  Grid,
  styled
} = window['MaterialUI'];


const App = () => {

    const GridTr = styled(Grid)(() => {
      return {
        height: '30px',
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
        },
      };
    });

    return ( < GridTr data-testid="grid-tr" > My Grid Component < /GridTr>)
    }



    ReactDOM.createRoot(
      document.getElementById("root")
    ).render( <
      App / >
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```